# How to emulate IE7 and FF2?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I build a webpage and in IE8 + FF3 it goes well, but a friend opens it in ie7 and it's terrible.

How can I emulate IE7 / other things / FF2 in my Windows 7 envoirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) for IE 5.5 to 8 for emulation. You can add on DebugBar (by the same developer) into IETester for Firebug-like debugging.

However Firefox I'm not sure. The only thing I can think of is to download a clean FF 2 and install it on another computer.

Comment: Its worth noting that IE8 has a fair chunk of firebugesque developer capability built in

Comment: @Murph, yeah I'm not mentioning that part because most of it has been mentioned by other answers. but I do agree that it has developer capability, but not in emulated mode like IE6 or 5.5 in IETester.

Comment: Don't use this.  Use the Virtual PC images.  Mixing system DLLs in the way IETester does is dangerous and unsupported.

Comment: @jeffmaphone - IETester doesn't "mix" system DLL. Instead it installs the IE dlls into it's own directory and uses it isolated, leaving your original DLLs clean.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run in in a virtual machine as you can't have multiple versions of IE installed on the same machine the same time.

1. [Downlaod Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/virtualpc/default.mspx)
2. Download the [IE7 Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) image from Microsoft. There's also an IE6 image there.

You can also install FF2 on the virtual machines safely.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 has a Developer Tools utility under Toos->Developer Tools. You can change Compatibility Mode to view how the page would look in IE7. As for FF2, the only way I know of is to actually have FF2 installed. Maybe you can find an older download package?

Once the utility opens there is a **Browser Mode:** box on the top menu. Change that to IE7, and it will render the page as IE7 would.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the 'Superpreview' feature that comes with Expression Web 3, it has help me to get a page working with IE8,7 and even 6, along with FireFox. You can get a free trail if you can't get the full version.

Comment: Check out Scott Hanselman's post on Expression Web 3, it'll show you what’s possible http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MultiBrowserOrCrossBrowserTestingAndDeconstructingMicrosoftExpressionWebSuperPreview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As for Firefox, you can use a [portable version](http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+2.0+portable).

Answer (score 0):

Various options locally:

- Run multiple virtual machines hosting different browsers (or combinations of browsers)
- The latest version of expression has a fairly comprehensive browser comparison tool
- There are some clever IE hacks out there too.

Also online

- Browsercam (and similar sites)
- Adobe [Browserlab](http://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html) possibly - not sure how "live" it is yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of simulators, one at least from MS to let you view in different IE browser versions. However they are simulators so may not accurately reflect the actual browser. Another way, but it might be over the top for your purposes is to install VM's and put the real browser in each VM to do the testing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently using Internet Explorer Collection which gives me over a dozen versions of IE, not that I test that many but it's interesting to look back at occasionally.